# How to configure .zshrc for specfic os

Tags: zsh

I want to use `emacs` from `Applications` folder when I'm using Mac, but I'm using same `.zshrc` in Ubuntu.

```
alias emacs='/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient'
```

So I want to create this alias for only when I'm using `OS X`. How can I get a OS name in `.zshrc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check if you are not running linux. If `uname` does not exist in Mac, the `if` clause will fail too.

```
if [ "$(uname 2> /dev/null)" != "Linux" ]; then
    alias emacs='vim'
fi
```

Comment: `uname` exists on Mac.  Mac is POSIX-compatible.

Answer (score 28):

I also share my Zsh startup between multiple operating systems.  You could use a `case` statement for those commands which are system-specific:

```
case `uname` in
  Darwin)
    # commands for OS X go here
  ;;
  Linux)
    # commands for Linux go here
  ;;
  FreeBSD)
    # commands for FreeBSD go here
  ;;
esac
```

Alternatively you can split off system-specific startup into files called (say) `.zshrc-Darwin`, `.zshrc-Linux`, etc., and then `source` the required one near the end of your `.zshrc`:

```
source "${ZDOTDIR:-${HOME}}/.zshrc-`uname`"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was searching for

Answer (score 16):

Checking environment variable `$OSTYPE` is preferred, cause it's more lightweighted compared with running the external command `uname`.

`OSTYPE` is set by ZSH the shell itself.

> OSTYPE
>
> The operating system, as determined at compile time.
>
> http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Set-By-The-Shell

#### Example

```bsh
# for ZSH
case "$OSTYPE" in
  darwin*)
    # ...
  ;;
  linux*)
    # ...
  ;;
  dragonfly*|freebsd*|netbsd*|openbsd*)
    # ...
  ;;
esac
```

#### Reference

- [Mature usage of `OSTYPE` in zsh's source code](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/71bc1296edfc548751354f4bf5832aba3fcd0b95/Completion/Unix/Command/_install#L24-L76)
- [Use "$OSTYPE" instead of "$(uname)" for OS detection in Bash](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/issues/433)

**Note**: Available `OSTYPE` values in Bash are a little different with the values in ZSH.